# Increase gravity in secondary

Tags: specific-gravity, secondary

I added a pot of coffee to my secondary without thinking much about the water content. Now the SG is lower than I want (weak body). Could I put it back into the kettle and boil the excess water off without destroying it?  Any other options?

Comment: [homebrewtalk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=56173) suggests adding maltodextrine.

Comment: Add sugar or freeze out water. I would not boil again because of flavor changes and evaporating alcohol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't boil it.

I would not just add sugar as this will be converted straight to alcohol and thin out the body/mouth feel further. Todd's suggestion to add some maltodextrine will give you a fuller body, but without adding any alcohol as most of the longer poly saccharides are unconvertible by yeast.

I would add a little sugar and a little of the maltodextrine, to give you the ABV you wanted to account for the extra volume and add a bit of body back that you have thinned out.

Also you could bottle it, and let it carb up, as the carbonation will help a little with the perception of body and mouthfeel.

When I add coffee I normally add the grounds and let it steep for a 1-2 weeks or I add a couple of shots of espresso, both to secondary.

The last coffee/chocolate stout I did the coffee and cocoa went straight into the primary and I still got a fair amount coming through in the bottles. I did add twice as much as the recipe suggested to compensate for the CO2 carrying off the aromas. This had no secondary and went straight into bottles from the Primary.

Comment: I find the opposite - that carbonation lightens the body and mouthfeel. Is it just me?